# Find the one-hundredth-smallest positive integer that can be written using only the digits $1$, $3$, and $5$ in base $7$.

Tags: number-theory

> Find the one-hundredth-smallest positive integer that can be written using only the digits $1$, $3$, and $5$ in base $7$.

So, I came across this problem in an old contest I did in 2018, and I still don't know how to solve it. I honestly don't even know where to start. Could someone please help me? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Excuse me, but you didn't specify if any operation has to be done on them or just use them as they are.

Comment: Oh, ok... Base 7 ?

Comment: Yeah it's in base 7

Comment: Hmm...Just using those three digits ?

Comment: How many such 1-digit numbers are there?  How many 2-digit numbers are there?  Can you at least determine the number of (base 7) digits in the requested number?  As well as whether it is in the first, middle, or last third of all such numbers?

Comment: What kind of answer is expected ? Is it in the decimal system ?

Comment: yeah I think it's the decimal system

Comment: For added context, the problem is on the fourth page of [this handout](https://cwhmathclub.weebly.com/uploads/1/0/7/3/107383853/7-7-18_problems.pdf). My googling skills are apparently not strong enough to determine what book the handout is photocopied from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just list them out in base $7$ first, and I think this won’t take you too much time. In fact, it’s actually fast.

1-digit numbers in base $7$ : There are $3$.

2-digit numbers in base $7$ : There are $9$.

3-digit numbers in base $7$ : There are $27$.

And now consider 4-digit numbers in base $7$.

Starts with $1$ (which is $1$ _ _ _ ) : There are $27$.

Starts with $3$ (which is $3$ _ _ _ ) : There are $27$.

So far we have $93$ numbers satisfying the condition.

Start with $5$ : $5111,5113,5115,5131,5133,5135,5151$

The answer is $5151$(base $7$) , which is $1800$ in base $10$.